# Display single element of array on multiple page controls

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, element, uipagecontrol

The following code is using page control to display images. I would like to use the same loop to display a single element of the array on each page. Right now the code displays a,b,c on all of the pages. I want it to display just one letter so page 1 a page 2 b etc.

```
@IBOutlet var lz: UILabel!
var judo = ["a","b","c"]
var output = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrol.delegate = self

    for image in 0...2 {
        output += " \(judo[image])"

        let imageTo = UIImage(named: "\(image).png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageTo)
        let xCord = view.frame.midX + view.frame.width * CGFloat(image)
        contenetWidth += view.frame.width
        scrol.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    lz.text = output
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the label or image?

Comment: As far as I understand, You are appending text to a single string and setting it to the label. There is only once label and overtime it will show same text.

Comment: create UILabel and set its value within the for loop

Comment: @Johnykutty the problem is that on the label it should only display 1 letter at a time and now it is displaying 3 letters. The whole array. I want the array to display 1 letter on one page.

Comment: I think you should do @iParesh's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewWillEndDragging`

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let index = targetContentOffset.pointee.x / view.frame.width
        self.lz.text = self.judo[Int(index)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for image in 0...2 {

        output += " \(judo[image])"

        ...

        let xCord = view.frame.midX + view.frame.width * CGFloat(image)
        let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x:xCord,y:0,width:50,height:30))
        label.text = output
        scrol.addSubview(label)

        ...
 }
```